# Where is the disk folder location of an Entity Framework database?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/new-database) indicates that an app using the code-first approach can simply specify the model, and the database will be created if it does not already exist.

But I want my app to store it's data in a database on the end-user's hard-disk. So I can refer to localdb (for SQL Server) in my connection string, but I still don't know what folder on the user's machine will have the database files.

How can a user back up her data files, if she doesn't know where they are?

Is there some way to ask the `DbContext` object where it's files are stored?

I know I can specify the path of the database when it is created via SQL, but I've been told that it is not good form to mix EF-style database interaction with non-EF database interaction (from ADO.NET).

Comment: You'll need to send a custom SQL query to get the file locations, e.g. `SELECT name, physical_name AS current_file_location
FROM sys.master_files`. [How to send a raw query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql)

Comment: Cool - thanks, @JohnWu, I'll give that a try.

Comment: @JohnWu , I'm having trouble getting this to work...  I can't seem to get the SQL query to the DbContext correctly.  It seems like I have 2 options for submitting the query:  context.Database.SqlQuery(<Type>, query) or context.<T>.SqlQuery(query).  Neither of these work for me, because I can't seem to get the correct <Type>...  Can you show a line or 2 of code for this...?

Comment: Think you'd have to define a type just for this resultset. Seems like a hassle. Personally I would skip EF and use `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` directly. There's no rule saying you can't.

Comment: Hmmm...  I'll have to look at it, as I've focused mainly on EF up to now...

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft documentaion [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15#description):

> User database files are stored where the user designates, typically
>   somewhere in the C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ folder.

So the person or setup program installing the SQL Express localdb knows where the database is.

**EDIT:**
To set the connection string at runtime, you can pass a connection string, instead of a connectionstring name, to your db context. You can create your connection string on your own or use a [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8).

```cs
// Manually build the connection string
var connectionString = "Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=" + pathToDatabase;

var dbContext = new YourDBContext(connectionString);
```

Comment: Thanks, @bdongus, for your response... "So the person or setup program installing the SQL Express localdb knows where the database is."  I can't very well expect every end user of my app to set up a database.  I suspect my installer must do that.  But I really wanted my code to do that when it failed to find/open an existing database.

Comment: Well. Then try AttachDbFileName to connect to the locally deployed database file.

Comment: can you give me an example in a couple lines of code?  I only see references to this in the documentation for LocalDbConnectionFactory, which I haven't been using, and I don't see how to query this value or set it...

Comment: You don't need code to set it. Just edit your connection string in your config. Like this: Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=true ;AttachDbFileName=D:\Data\MyDB1.mdf

Comment: I think you're still missing my earlier point. This is a local database on each user's machine.  So I can't specify C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ in a config file, when UserName changes for each user.  It must be determined at run-time, i.e. in code.  But how do I specify the connection string at run-time using EF?  This seems like a situation that many apps would have, but I see pretty much nothing about it online...